Excel VBA: Use MsgBox if Replace finds nothing to replace
I'm using a simple code to find values in a range and if that value is found, all instances of it are cleared with a "".
The code:
Sub Clear()
    Range("A1:R34").Replace What:=Range("U3"), Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlWhole
    Range("U3").ClearContents
End Sub

So if the value typed into U3 is found within the range then those cells that contain that value are cleared. This code works fine and those instances are cleared if found, however I would like a dialogue box to appear If the value in U3 is NOT found in my range. So I would use MsgBox "Invalid Order Number". I can't figure out how to place this into my code. I feel I need an IF and Then but I'm a novice with this so not sure.
Basically I want the code to be like this:
Sub Clear()

    Range("A1:R34").Replace What:=Range("U3"), Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlWhole
    'If (if the above Replace finds nothing) Then MsgBox "Invalid Order Number"

    Range("U3").ClearContents


I don't know the syntax to get this to work.

Docs for Range.Replace suggest it returns a Boolean indicating whether any matches were found, but in my testing it always returns True.  One workaround is to use Find() to see if there's any match, then use Replace if the return value from Find() is not Nothing

you could also do a very quick "CountIf" function and if equals 0, you can do a msgbox.

Docs for Range.Replace suggest it returns a Boolean indicating whether any matches were found, but in my testing it always returns True. One workaround is to use Find() to see if there's any match, then use Replace if the return value from Find() is not Nothing
Sub Clear()
    Dim cFind as Range, ws as worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or specific named sheet
    Set cFind = ws.Range("U3")
    With ws.Range("A1:R34")
        If Not .Find(What:=cFind.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            .Replace What:=cFind.Value, Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlWhole
            cFind.ClearContents
        Else
            Msgbox "Invalid order number: " & cFind.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Thanks Tim. I read your inital comment before you edited it and I used range.replace=FALSE after changing the line to an IF and the code still worked but I never got the MsgBox when it found nothing to I guess you are right. Anyway, your code above works perfect. Thank you.

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

Starting a mock-up with the following expectations:

U3 is the lookup value
A1:R34 is the lookup range
Replace can be used for all instances

With sheets(1)
    dim lookUpRng as range:  Set lookUpRange = .Range("A1:R34")
    dim lookUpVal as range:  Set lookUpVal = .Range("U3") 'Treated as Range, but if you know if it's long/double/string then lookUpVal = .Range("U3").Value would be more approprate to not re-reference the cell and its property
    If Application.Countif(lookUpRng,lookUpVal.value) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Value not found within A1:R34:  " & lookUpVal.value
    Else
        lookUpRng.Replace What:=Range("U3"), Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlWhole
    End If
End with

